# pyautogui how do i write outside my code editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pyautogui

i am trying to make a macro and i have run into some problems. whenever i try to make it type something outside vscode the program runs but it doesn't type anything. it works fine typing inside vscode though so i know it works. i have run into this issue with another module pynput as well i also tried adjusting the permissions but it didn't do anything different.

Here's my code:

```
import pyautogui
import time
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.write("Hello World! ", interval=0.01)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The sample code [works fine on my machine](https://imgur.com/ZiQiPrJ). Can you provide more details about your running code?

Comment: that is all the code i had and i figured out it was because i was using linux development environment on chrome os sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program was working exactly as intended it was just not interacting with my os properly